# How to support different stages for testing facebook authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

I am developing a rails application using omniauth-facebook for authentication. I have 3 different stages (localhost, staging.mycompany.com, production.mycompany.com) for testing purposes

How should I register the facebook application, should I do it for all 3 stages
https://developers.facebook.com/x/apps/appid/settings/ (appid is the reference to my Facebook application)

Since the Site URL will be different for all 3 stages above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just register 3 different apps and create a yaml file with those keys (social.yml). Something like:

```
development:
  fb_key: 123
  fb_secret: abc
production:
  fb_key: 345
  fb_secret: def
```

Then create a global variable of it in an initializer:

`SOCIAL_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{::Rails.root}/config/social.yml")[::Rails.env]`

This way you always use the right key for the environment your in.